# CoreNLP MaxentTagger Data Format Error

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, illegalargumentexception

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP for NLP processing and am in the process of training the POS tagger with more domain specific data. However, for some reason, the trainer is throwing "Data format error" when I run it with the properties file I've got. Here's the context:

**Training file**

```
Please#UH let#VBP us#PRP know#VB if#IN you#PRP have#VBP any#DT other#JJ thoughts#NNS that#WDT...
```

(Basically a very long 1-line word + tag set.)

**Training properties file**

```
         model = special_postagger.tagger
                  arch = words(-1,1),unicodeshapes(-1,1),order(2),suffix(4)
          wordFunction = 
             trainFile = /path/to/POS_trainer1.csv
       closedClassTags = 
closedClassTagThreshold = 40
curWordMinFeatureThresh = 2
                 debug = false
           debugPrefix = 
          tagSeparator = #
              encoding = UTF-8
            iterations = 100
                  lang = 
  learnClosedClassTags = false
      minFeatureThresh = 5
         openClassTags = 
rareWordMinFeatureThresh = 10
        rareWordThresh = 5
                search = qn
                  sgml = false
          sigmaSquared = 0.5
                 regL1 = 1.0
             tagInside = 
              tokenize = true
      tokenizerFactory = 
      tokenizerOptions = 
               verbose = false
        verboseResults = true
  veryCommonWordThresh = 250
              xmlInput = 
            outputFile = 
          outputFormat = slashTags
   outputFormatOptions = 
              nthreads = 1
```

**Command Run**

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -prop myProps.props
```

But for some reason, I get this error message:

```
warning: no language set, no open-class tags specified, and no closed-class tags specified; assuming ALL tags are open class tags
TaggerExperiments: adding word/tags
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format error: can't find delimiter "#" in word "as" (line 2 of /path/to/POS_Trainer1.csv)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.io.TextTaggedFileReader.primeNext(TextTaggedFileReader.java:74)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.io.TextTaggedFileReader.<init>(TextTaggedFileReader.java:34)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.io.TaggedFileRecord.reader(TaggedFileRecord.java:111)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.ReadDataTagged.<init>(ReadDataTagged.java:52)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerExperiments.<init>(TaggerExperiments.java:86)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.trainAndSaveModel(MaxentTagger.java:1140)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.runTraining(MaxentTagger.java:1207)
at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.main(MaxentTagger.java:1839)
```

Comment: This error indicates that you have a word without a tag (or without a delimiter between the word and the tag) in your training data. Did you check that all words have a tag?

Comment: Hmm...I took the original data (which is *supposed to be* one word/tag per line with a backslash in between) and ran this perl script over it for every row: if($row !~ /(.*)(\\.*)/)...turned up nothing, while the reverse if($row =~ /(.*)(\\.*)/) printed every line...

Comment: Never mind, you're right...it's a bit more complicated than just the pattern I noted above. But essentially, yes -- it's an issue with not having the ideal word/tag pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here: the training file *must* have a *perfect* format of [word][delimiter][tag], or else it will throw fatal runtime error. You can use whatever delimiter you want, such as the hashtag # symbol, for example, but if there are:

- whitespaces
- missing tags

between the [word][delimiter][tag] pattern, it will fail.